# Не запускается форма Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

```
   static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form intro = new Form2();
        intro.Show();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        intro.Close();
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
```

Форма2 это заставка,но она не запускается.Почему?

Comment: попробуйте Form2 intro = new Form2();

Comment: а разница? \\\\\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем коде действие развивается по такому сценарию:

```
Form intro = new Form2(); // создать форму, ее пока нет на экране
intro.Show(); // форма появится на экране, когда у системы будет возможность ее отрисовать
Thread.Sleep(2000); // ничего не делать в этом потоке, то есть - вообще
intro.Close(); // убрать форму с экрана
```

---

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

  Form intro = new Form2();
  intro.Show();
  Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  intro.Close();

  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,но почему как я написал не получается?

Comment: Потому, что вы останавливаете поток, в котором происходит обработка UI.